# Flex: pack database file within the .apk file?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I wrote a mobile application ( AIR ) which storing some strings into a SqlLite database.
It is external database file, which shall reside in a sub folder of the main application folder.
So far everything works flawless while debugging on the PC, but when i am exporting the application into .APK file the result package does not contain the database, neither the database folder.

- how to add the database folder and the database file into the result android package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flash Builder, when exporting a release build; switch over to the "Package Contents" tab and select your database file / database directory in the "Package Contents."

Comment: got it... ( i think ) - i have placed manually the folders and files just before build it inside bin-release-temp and then they becaming available into the result. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Awesome!  Odd that you had to get the stuff available manually, though.

Comment: yep. it is very strange indeed :| maybe it will be fixed in Flash Builder 5 :)